# how to add preserveAspectRatio to svg used as background-image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm having trouble with a svg pattern background that is not repeating on the x-axis in IE11 (and probably other IEs) and the Android native browser.
Apparently I should add `preserveAspectRatio: "none slice"` to the svg element, but what if the svg is used as background-image?

CSS

```
header.logoheader:after {
    background-image: url('patroon5.svg');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

(I'm using the `:after` selector so the transparent pattern covers the div)

In my HTML there is no svg element to add the `preserveAspectRatio` to. I'm thinking this is because of the `:after` selector.

Anyone got an solution?

Comment: That property should be in the base SVG code...not the "image"....but the image will behave like any other image regardless of whether it's an SVG or not.

Comment: If it should behave like any other image, why isn't it repeating on the x-axis in IE11 and the Android native browser?

Comment: Can't test without a demo.

Answer (score 3):

You can either edit the background image svg file to include it or alternatively use an [SVG fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) i.e.

```
background-image: url('patroon5.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))');
```

Comment: You can omit 'slice' here, since it gets ignored when <align> is 'none', see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Had this kind of problem before on IE. To fix it you have to edit your svg file then remove the set `width` and `height` assuming you have `viewBox` set in there. Then add `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid"` as an attribute.

e.g.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 1024" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was looking for this for days, works like charm when removing width and height from sag and adding preserveAspectRatio="none".  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid" seems to have no effect though